# Pyspark - Defining custom schema for a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to read a csv file, and trying to store it in a dataframe, but when I try to make the `ID` column of the type `StringType`, it is not happening in the expected way.

```
table_schema = StructType([StructField('ID', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Tax_Percentage(%)', IntegerType(), False),
                     StructField('Effective_From', TimestampType(), False),
                     StructField('Effective_Upto', TimestampType(), True)])

# CSV options
infer_schema = "true"
first_row_is_header = "true"
delimiter = ","


df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .option("schema", table_schema) \
  .load(file_location)



display(df)
```

Below is the schema getting generated after running the above code:

```
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
ID:integer
Name:string
Tax_Percentage(%):integer
Effective_From:string
Effective_Upto :string
```

The `ID` is typed to `integer` where I am expecting it to be String, despite the custom schema provided. Same with the columns `Effective_From` and `Effective_Upto`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be

```
.schema(table_schema) \
```

instead of

```
.option("schema", table_schema) \
```

Also, you don't need the `.option("inferSchema", "true") \` if you are providing schema definition :)