# Is there a way to ensure that PySpark dataframes correctly recognize the data type of columns read from CSV and parquet files?

Tags: pyspark

I'm reading several parquet and csv data files into a pyspark dataframe. As you can imagine, the dataframe doesn't recognize the correct data type of certain columns - for example, some integers are categorized as Strings etc.
Is there an approach to auto-detect and convert data frame columns into the right data type from the get-go?

I've tried googling and  complex if-else statements, but these don't generalize well.

Comment: You can define your shema and add it when you read the file. This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901493/pyspark-defining-custom-schema-for-a-dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark - Defining custom schema for a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901493/pyspark-defining-custom-schema-for-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

PySpark has the `inferSchema=True` option when reading some files like CSV but most of the time you will have to define the schema previously.

A easy way to do it using DDL:

```
my_schema = "Name String, Age Int, Contry String"
spark.read.csv("file.csv", schema=my_schema)
```

The hard way is using the spark functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField("Name", StringType(), False),
 StructField("Age", IntegerType(), False),
 StructField("Country", StringType(), False)])
```